# CakePHP - live search with AJAX

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP and trying to come up with Idea of the live search. I have a very big table (6000+ entries) and would like to use input field to search entries based on the user input. But I am not sure where to start because then I cannot search all of the items in the controller as I used to.

This is what I did using select2, but I would like to combine it, I would like results to be shown via select where user can select multiple items, but my function should search just based on user input, whereas my way just filters all searched items.

[image]

```
<?php 
      echo $this->Form->create('Items', array('url' => 'itemToAdd', )) 
      echo $this->Form->input('itemToAdd', array('options' => $itemsToAdd));
      echo $this->Form->end(__('Add this item')) 
?>
```

So $itemsToAdd is a variable that is instatiated in the controller and gets all the entries.

```
$itemsToAdd = $this->Item->find('list');
```

Items schema:

```
items(id, code, name, description, created, modified)
```

But could I get some directions how could i tell AJAX only to search entries which are corresponding to the user input. I am not sure how to implement this on the technical level.

Comment: Do you have multiple search field/box? try to put some screenshot and table schema so we can understand in details.

Answer (score 1):

1. Send the input to the server.
2. Evaluate input.
3. Construct a search query
4. Return results
5. Render results on frontend

For this you need knowledge of HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP and SQL.